# Convert datatable to list with relation

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

I have a some table(one table) It's just example - real time table so huge.

```
DevisionId  EmployeeId  date        Hour    
1130107     3011657     2014-10-11  8   
1130107     3011657     2014-10-12  1   
1130107     3011660     2014-10-11  8   
1130107     3011660     2014-10-12  6
```

and i want to convert this datatable to list of object lists, please show me the best way how to do this.

As an example like this

```
public class Devision 
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public List<Employees> Employee {get;set;}
    Devision(int id, List<Employees> emp)
    {
        ID = id;
        Employees = emp;
    }
}

public class Employees 
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public List<Info> Item {get;set;}
    Employees(int id, List<Info> info)
    {
        ID = id;
        Item = info;
    }
}

public class Info 
{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public float Hour {get;set;}
    Info(DateTime dtime, float hour)
    {
        Date = dtime;
        Hour = hour;
    }
}
```

I what to get by this object by LINQ, and if you can is not Queryable level(but it is no matter).
Let's start from getting `LINQ` like :

```
var mytab = Table.AsEnumerable();
        var itemses =
            mytab.Select(
```

ThankX.

Comment: Shouldn't your class be `Employee` and the property in `Devision` should be `List<Employee> Employees`?  Or do you not want to group the employees under the same devision object?

Comment: Yes you are right - changed

Comment: You haven't even mentioned your desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
List<Devision> devisions = Table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new Devision(
        row.Field<int>("DevisionId"),
        new Employees(
            row.Field<int>("EmployeeId"), 
            new Info(row.Field<DateTime>("date"), row.Field<float>("Hour")))))
    .ToList();
```

Note that your constructors have to be `public`. Also, [`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) does not do any casting, you have to provide the correct type or convert the values to the target types (or change the way the table is filled).

---

Now that you have changed the question completely it seems that you actually want to group by `DevisionId` and `EmployeeId` and initialize a `List<Employees>` for every group. Then have a look:

```
List<Devision> devisions = Table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new {
        EmpID = row.Field<int>("EmployeeId"),
        DevID = row.Field<int>("DevisionId")})
    .Select(devEmpGroup => new Devision(
        devEmpGroup.Key.DevID, devEmpGroup 
        .Select(row => new Employees(
            devEmpGroup.Key.EmpID,
            new Info(row.Field<DateTime>("date"), row.Field<float>("Hour"))))
        .ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

---

Now that also the property `Info` in `Employees` is a `List<Info>` this should be for you:

```
List<Devision> devisions = Table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("DevisionId"))
    .Select(devGrp => new Devision(
        devGrp.Key,
        devGrp.GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("EmployeeId"))
               .Select(g => new Employees(
                   g.Key,
                   g.Select(r => new Info(r.Field<DateTime>("date"), r.Field<float>("Hour")))
                    .ToList()))
              .ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The OP changed Devision to take a list of Employees.

Comment: With some mistakes for `Employees(int id, Info info)` but i need to `public Employees(int id, List<Info> info)` - i'm so sorry but if you can change in correct way. ThanX

Comment: last one list should be a `List<date, hours>` - please correct now it selecting like a `List<empid, new(date, hours)>`

Comment: @Hurricane: you've lost me. There is no `List<date, hours>`. A generic list can only have one type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry i was wrong in a last one comment, list selecting like `List<empid, List<date, hours>>` but only - `List<date, hours> ` have just one element